# How to get ObjectID as String from mongo-go-driver cursor?

Tags: go, bson, mongo-go

I would like to get ObjectID as a string because I have other storage types, so I want to avoid to use primitive.ObjectID in my struct to keep the layers independent.
I'm new to Golang, thanks.

```
package listing

type Card struct {
    ID       string
    Hanzi    string
    Pinyin   string
    Traducao string
}
```

My storage file:
    package storage

```
func (m *Mongodb)GetCards() []*listing.Card {
    var list []*listing.Card

    collection := m.Client.Database("flashcards").Collection("cards")
    cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Erro buscando cards:", err)
    }
    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var card listing.Card
        err = cur.Decode(&card)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Erro decodificando documento", err)
        }
        list = append(list, &card)
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: which ObjectID are you talking about?

Answer (score 6):

Like you, I was looking for a solution to keep modules as independent as possible and keep coupling levels low.
I scratched my head A LOT but in the end, I found this. I hope it's a valid and clear, solution.

You can use a custom type that implements the [ValueMarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#ValueMarshaler) interface: so you have to implement
[MarshalValue](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#MarshalValue)  func!

```
type Card struct {
    ID       MyObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    CardSuit string     `bson:"cardSuit"`
}

type MyObjectID string

func (id MyObjectID) MarshalBSONValue() (bsontype.Type, []byte, error) {
    p, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(string(id))
    if err != nil {
        return bsontype.Null, nil, err
    }

    return bson.MarshalValue(p)
}
```

ID is practically a `string`, but with the custom marshaller, it will be saved as an ObjectID in Mongo, and parsed correctly during unmarshalling.

[Here is a working example](https://play.golang.org/p/OUbz3VVlhIp), obviously, you need mongo to make it run.

[Related question that helped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61314761/4970650)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out.
I created another struct just to hold the ObjectId

```
type HexId struct {
    ID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
}
```

then I used Hex() to pass the value to Card.ID

```
err = cur.Decode(&card)
err = cur.Decode(&hexId)
card.ID = hexId.ID.Hex()
```

Now I can use it to make links.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works out of the box when having the bson annotation (version 5.0.6):

```
type User struct {
    Id   string `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string `bson:"name" json:"name"`
}
```

Comment: version 5.0.6 of what library ? The latest of mongo-go-driver is 1.11.2 as of March 2023

Comment: Works for me too, with Mongo version: 5.0.5 and driver version: go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.10.2

Answer (score -2):

Use `bson:"-"` for ignore `ObjectID` in response and `json:"-"` for ignoring in database.
And you don't need to decode two times.

```
type Card struct {
    ObjectID primitive.ObjectID `json:"-" bson:"_id"`
    ID       string             `bson:"-"`
    Hanzi    string
    Pinyin   string
    Traducao string
}

err = cur.Decode(&card)
card.ID = card.ObjectID.Hex()
```

Comment: It works but as I said, I want to keep my layers independent. I don't want database specific types on this layer.
However, this solution avoids decode the cursor twice.
Thanks  Eklavya